# MVC2: How submit data from Partial view to his controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this model:

```
public class Package
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have a **Create**'s view for creating a new Package and one or many **Create product**'s **PartialView**.

How I can submit the Product informations to the Product's controller without leave the View?

Here is my Product's Partialview code:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Product", new AjaxOptions())) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity) %>
        </div>

<%--    <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>--%>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

Thank you

Comment: @SLaks, yes I know, but which call do? How pass fields data to the controller?

Comment: With the form you've got above, you just need to uncomment the submit button and <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> at the top. You won't need to write any javascript code at all if you do that

Comment: This form (Product Form) is in an other form (Package form) and even if I use this script, it's the Create of Package which is called and not the Product form. I think I must use a $.post method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AJAX to solve your problem. The code pode below post 3 values to YourController in YourAction.

```
jQuery('#YourButton').click(function (event) {

    var jqxhr = $.post("YourController/YourAction", {
        lastName: $("#tbLastName").val(),
        firstName: $("#tbFirstName").val(),
        id: $("#id").val()
    },
    function (data) {
        $('#WhereResultAppear').html(data); //can be deleted
    })

    .success(function () {
        $('#InCaseOfSuccess').html(data); //can be deleted
    })

    .error(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        $('#InCaseOfError').html(data); //can be deleted
    })

    .complete(function () {
        $('#WhenActionIsComplete').html(data); //can be deleted
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes I will use $.post(). Thank

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to your form in the partial view. and then use JQuery to send data by serializing the form.

```
$.post("controller/action", $("#formId").serialize(),
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

And in the controller

```
   Package pakage = new Package();

    UpdateModel(pakage );
```

Comment: I load the partial view with jQuery's load method, and when I do that, the partial view is rendered, but the form of the partial view doesn't!

Comment: I've updated the answer to give you the code of the PartialView

Answer (score 0):

Although you can write code to serialize the data as the other answers mention, I would consider surrounding the fields in an

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionOnController", new AjaxOptions{}))
{

}
```

This will do it all for you (as long as you include the necessary javascript e.g. jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js)

Take a look at the [AjaxOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.aspx) documentation. This allows you to (amongst other things) update another section after posting the values back. You can use this to indicate success

Martin